# How to properly add a new object to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to add a new Object to an array each time I call a function with Javascript, but it appears that the object is created correctly but when I check for the size of the array it is always 0. What can it be?

```
var comments = new Array();

function validateComment() {
var x = document.forms["commentForm"]["commentSection"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("There's nothing to comment, write something to proceed.");
    return false;
} else {
    var comment = {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Surname",
        text:x
    }; 
    comments.push(comment);
 }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where/how are you inspecting `comments`? How do you know the object is created correctly? How is `validateComment` called? Does `document.forms["commentForm"]["commentSection"]` exist?

Comment: Yes, I check for the creation using the inspect element tool in google chrome and every attribute is created fine according to that.

Comment: "Inspect element" is for inspecting DOM elements. `comment` is a JavaScript object, so I don't understand how this is supposed to work (unless you are creating DOM elements from the object, but where?). Please provide a **complete** example and more information (see my questions in the previous comment).

Comment: Here's a picture of the creation of the object http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHaRK.png

Comment: Ah, so you are setting a breakpoint (although that looks like Firebug, not Chrome). At least you know how to debug JS! And what makes you think it doesn't get added to the array?

Comment: Because later I do 'alert(comments.length)' and it always tells me it is '0' even though I've added many objects.

Comment: Where/how "later"? Again, this would be so much easier if you provided a **complete** example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Below in that same function :/ but in the picture I deleted that line haha

Comment: Sorry I'm such a noob here

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the information you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/w45d6f3j/ .